# Blazor page to MVC page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor

I try to logout in code in a procedure on a Blazorpage.

```
var url = $"{navigationManager.BaseUri}Identity/Account/Logout";
navigationManager.NavigateTo(url);
```

That doesn't work. I got the message
Sorry, there's nothing at this address.

Odd, because the address directly in the addressbar of the browser, brings me to the logout page.

What do I miss that blazor does not seem to find the logout

Answer (score 3):

Force a reload with the second parameter your not using.

`navigationManager.NavigateTo(url,true);`

Comment: Super. Simple, and plain.  Never looked at the paramaeter. Thank you